# jQuery automatically fade in next html element then loop to restart

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have:

```
<a id="item<?php echo $i; ?>">...</a>
<a id="item<?php echo $i; ?>">...</a>
...
```

Where $i will be the value of the current iteration starting from 1 and will render something like:

```
<a id="item1">...</a>
<a id="item2">...</a>
...
```

What I need is a script to keep visible only the first element, then after a few seconds (lets say 4-5) fade out and fade in the next one. And repeat this cycle until last element.
Then loop to start it all over again.

No "pause" or next/prev elements needed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this JS:  ( http://jsfiddle.net/KWmgf/ )

```
var fadeLoop = function($el) {
    $el.fadeOut(4000, function() {
        var $next = $el.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) {
            $next = $el.siblings(":first");
        }
        $next.fadeIn(4000, function() {
            fadeLoop($next);
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#item1").siblings().hide();
    fadeLoop($("#item1"));
});
```

Comment: Works great in the fiddle but inside my content just hides itself after time set... Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your full HTML?  Maybe there's something that I am not accounting for.  Or please create a fiddle from your HTML.

Comment: This is working fine now! other important elements were siblings, just had to put them inside a div and it worked out just fine

Answer (score 0):

Set all `a` (or better add some `CLASS attribute` to them) elements style to `display:none` axcept the first one.

And add script:

```
setInterval(function() {
var $visible = $('.CLASS:visible');
$visible.hide();

if ( $visible.is(':last') ){
   $visible.siblings(':first').show()
} else {
   $visible.next().show();
}
}, 3000);
```

replace `CLASS` with real `a` class name